# R, data.table or dplyr, long format splitting colnames

Tags: r, reshape

Imagine I have a dataframe with column names such as Mary1, Mary2, Mary3, Bob1, Bob2, Bob3, Pam1, Pam2, Pam3, and so on, but with many more columns.

Let's put a simpler reproducible example.

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame()
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,round(runif(30),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,round(runif(30),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(3,round(runif(30),3)))
colnames(mydata) <- c("id", paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=3), 1:3))
```

that gives:

```
id    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3    C1    C2    C3    D1    D2    D3    E1    E2    E3    F1    F2    F3    G1    G2    G3    H1    H2    H3    I1    I2    I3    J1    J2    J3  ...
1  0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 0.898 0.945 0.661 0.629 0.062 0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.770 0.498 0.718  0.992 0.380 0.777 0.935 0.212 0.652 0.126 0.267 0.386 0.013 0.382 0.870 0.340  ...
2  0.482 0.600 0.494 0.186 0.827 0.668 0.794 0.108 0.724 0.411 0.821 0.647 0.783 0.553 0.530 0.789 0.023  0.477 0.732 0.693 0.478 0.861 0.438 0.245 0.071 0.099 0.316 0.519 0.662 0.407  ...
3  0.913 0.294 0.459 0.332 0.651 0.258 0.479 0.766 0.084 0.875 0.339 0.839 0.347 0.334 0.476 0.892 0.864  0.390 0.777 0.961 0.435 0.713 0.400 0.325 0.757 0.203 0.711 0.122 0.245 0.143  ...
```

I want to get a long table format, like this:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame()
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,1,round(runif(10),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,2,round(runif(10),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,3,round(runif(10),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,1,round(runif(10),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,2,round(runif(10),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,3,round(runif(10),3)))
colnames(mydata) <- c("id","N", LETTERS[1:10])
```

that's:

```
 id  N     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  1  1 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 0.898 0.945 0.661 0.629 0.062
  1  2 0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.770 0.498 0.718 0.992 0.380 0.777
  1  3 0.482 0.600 0.494 0.186 0.827 0.668 0.794 0.108 0.724 0.411
  2  1 0.935 0.212 0.652 0.126 0.267 0.386 0.013 0.382 0.870 0.340
  2  2 0.821 0.647 0.783 0.553 0.530 0.789 0.023 0.477 0.732 0.693
  2  3 0.478 0.861 0.438 0.245 0.071 0.099 0.316 0.519 0.662 0.407
```

How can I get it with data.table or dplyr/tidyr? or any other simple option.

If I try

```
melt(mydata, id=1)
```

the result is a single column.

I've been checking the official help and the vignettes but I can only find much simpler examples, with a small number of columns, the user specifies every one by hand,  and a single example of pattern() but I can't adapt it to my example.

Other threads use gsub, but it's confusing for me.

What I really want to do is a little bit more complicated, but I think this is the first step (I'll later cast it again).
Imagine my columns are Mary1, Mary2, Bob1, Bob2, Pam1, Pam2...
I want to create new columns with the differences of every two aforementioned: Mary1-Mary2, Bob1-Bob2, Pam1-Pam2...

Summarizing:  I don't want to write the name of all columns by hand but select them automatically removing the last digit.

PD: OK, I upgrade my question.
It must work not only for names such as A1, A2...  but also for longer names, such as

```
colnames(mydata) <- c("id", paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=3), rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=3), 1:3))
```

I don't mind the speed, I'm lookking for something simple, not cryptic.

Comment: Your problem seems more and more about how to use *regex* and less about reshaping. I'd suggest that you learn to use regex and develop based on any of the answers below.

Comment: It is worth the time invested to learn some regular expressions. `gsub`, `grep`, `grepl`, and many others provide a great opportunity for reducing code size and accomplishing tasks that may otherwise be impossible. This is one of my favorite [sites](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: @Arun I agree, but look at rawr solution, he doesn't use any complex regex nor needs uniques...

Comment: I found a little problem, most solutions you provide don't work if the columns with similar names aren't consecutive

Comment: I continue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023999/r-substracting-every-two-columns

Answer (score 5):

Here is one solution with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
mydata %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2'),
           sep = '(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])') %>%
  spread(key1, value)
```

Resulting output:

```
  id key2     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
1  1    1 0.266 0.908 0.945 0.062 0.687 0.498 0.380 0.212 0.267 0.382
2  1    2 0.372 0.202 0.661 0.206 0.384 0.718 0.777 0.652 0.386 0.870
3  1    3 0.573 0.898 0.629 0.177 0.770 0.992 0.935 0.126 0.013 0.340
4  2    1 0.482 0.186 0.794 0.411 0.783 0.789 0.732 0.861 0.071 0.519
5  2    2 0.600 0.827 0.108 0.821 0.553 0.023 0.693 0.438 0.099 0.662
6  2    3 0.494 0.668 0.724 0.647 0.530 0.477 0.478 0.245 0.316 0.407
7  3    1 0.913 0.332 0.479 0.875 0.347 0.892 0.777 0.713 0.757 0.122
8  3    2 0.294 0.651 0.766 0.339 0.334 0.864 0.961 0.400 0.203 0.245
9  3    3 0.459 0.258 0.084 0.839 0.476 0.390 0.435 0.325 0.711 0.143
```

Comment: You did it easy, but when I try it on my own I combine many things and it only works sometimes.
Thanks.

Comment: But it only works for the simple example, column names made with a single letter+one number.  Could you please expand it for column names such as Mary1, Mary2, Bob1, Bob2... ?

Comment: This is inefficient as shown in my [UseR15](http://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/93.pdf) talk and roundabout as explained in the [Reshaping vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: You just have to modify the `sep` argument to be a regex.

Comment: @Arun not everyone wants to use data.table.

Comment: @Gopala, if you'd seen the slide, you'd have noticed that I benchmarked data.table, base R *and* tidyr. And there's a nice solution from base R already provided for this answer.

Comment: @skan - edited with proper `sep` argument for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table::melt`:

```
require(data.table)
n = unique(gsub("[0-9]+$", "", names(mydata)[-1L]))
p = paste0("^", n)

melt(setDT(mydata), measure=patterns(p), value.name=n, variable.name="N")
#    id N     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
# 1:  1 1 0.266 0.908 0.945 0.062 0.687 0.498 0.380 0.212 0.267 0.382
# 2:  2 1 0.482 0.186 0.794 0.411 0.783 0.789 0.732 0.861 0.071 0.519
# 3:  3 1 0.913 0.332 0.479 0.875 0.347 0.892 0.777 0.713 0.757 0.122
# 4:  1 2 0.372 0.202 0.661 0.206 0.384 0.718 0.777 0.652 0.386 0.870
# 5:  2 2 0.600 0.827 0.108 0.821 0.553 0.023 0.693 0.438 0.099 0.662
# 6:  3 2 0.294 0.651 0.766 0.339 0.334 0.864 0.961 0.400 0.203 0.245
# 7:  1 3 0.573 0.898 0.629 0.177 0.770 0.992 0.935 0.126 0.013 0.340
# 8:  2 3 0.494 0.668 0.724 0.647 0.530 0.477 0.478 0.245 0.316 0.407
# 9:  3 3 0.459 0.258 0.084 0.839 0.476 0.390 0.435 0.325 0.711 0.143
```

Answer (score 4):

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame()
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,round(runif(30),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,round(runif(30),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(3,round(runif(30),3)))
colnames(mydata) <- c("id", paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=3), 1:3)) 

reshape(mydata, dir = 'long', varying = names(mydata)[-1], sep = '', timevar = 'N')

#     id N     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
# 1.1  1 1 0.266 0.908 0.945 0.062 0.687 0.498 0.380 0.212 0.267 0.382
# 2.1  2 1 0.482 0.186 0.794 0.411 0.783 0.789 0.732 0.861 0.071 0.519
# 3.1  3 1 0.913 0.332 0.479 0.875 0.347 0.892 0.777 0.713 0.757 0.122
# 1.2  1 2 0.372 0.202 0.661 0.206 0.384 0.718 0.777 0.652 0.386 0.870
# 2.2  2 2 0.600 0.827 0.108 0.821 0.553 0.023 0.693 0.438 0.099 0.662
# 3.2  3 2 0.294 0.651 0.766 0.339 0.334 0.864 0.961 0.400 0.203 0.245
# 1.3  1 3 0.573 0.898 0.629 0.177 0.770 0.992 0.935 0.126 0.013 0.340
# 2.3  2 3 0.494 0.668 0.724 0.647 0.530 0.477 0.478 0.245 0.316 0.407
# 3.3  3 3 0.459 0.258 0.084 0.839 0.476 0.390 0.435 0.325 0.711 0.143
```

Comment: Your method seems to work well even without regex expressions.  I've tried something similar with melt and it doesn't work