# Subtracting every two columns

Tags: regex, r

Imagine I have a dataframe like this (or the names of all months)

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame()
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,round(runif(20),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,round(runif(20),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(3,round(runif(20),3)))
colnames(mydata) <- c("id", paste0(rep(c('Mary', 'Bob', 'Dylan', 'Tom', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Tony', 'Luke', 'John', "Pam"), each=2), 1:2))
```

.

```
id Mary1 Mary2  Bob1  Bob2 Dylan1 Dylan2  Tom1  Tom2 Jane1 Jane2  Sam1  Sam2 Tony1 Tony2 Luke1 Luke2 John1 John2  Pam1  Pam2
1  0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908  0.202  0.898 0.945 0.661 0.629 0.062 0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.770 0.498 0.718 0.992 0.380 0.777
2  0.935 0.212 0.652 0.126  0.267  0.386 0.013 0.382 0.870 0.340 0.482 0.600 0.494 0.186 0.827 0.668 0.794 0.108 0.724 0.411
3  0.821 0.647 0.783 0.553  0.530  0.789 0.023 0.477 0.732 0.693 0.478 0.861 0.438 0.245 0.071 0.099 0.316 0.519 0.662 0.407
```

Usually with many more columns.

And I want to add columns (it's up to you to decide to add them to the right, or create a new dataframe with these new columns) substracting every two.. (*)

```
id, Mary1-Mary2,  Bob1-Bob2,  Dylan1-Dylan2,  Tom1-Tom2,  Jane1-Jane2,...
```

This operation is quite common.

I'd like to do it by name, not by position, to prevent problems if they are not consecutive.
It could even happen that some columns don't have it's "twin" column, just leave as is, or ignore this complication now.

(*)  The names of the columns have a prefix and a number.
Instead of just substracting two columns I could have groups of 5 and I may want to do something such as adding all numbers. A generic solution would be great.

I first tried to do it by convert it to long format, later operate with aggregate, and convert it back to wide format, but maybe it's much easier to do it directly in wide format.  I know the problem is mainly related to use efficiently regular expressions.

[R, data.table or dplyr, long format splitting colnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011952/r-data-table-or-dplyr-long-format-splitting-colnames)

I don't mind the speed but the simplest solution.
Any package is wellcome.

PD: All your codes fail if I add a lonely column.
set.seed(1)

```
mydata <- data.frame()
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(1,round(runif(21),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(2,round(runif(21),3)))
mydata <- rbind(mydata,c(3,round(runif(21),3)))
colnames(mydata) <- c(c("id", paste0(rep(c('Mary', 'Bob', 'Dylan', 'Tom', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Tony', 'Luke', 'John', "Pam"), each=2), 1:2)),"Lola" )
```

I know I could filter it out manually but it would be better if the result is the difference (*) of every pair and leave alone the lonely column. (In case of differences of groups of size two)

The best option would be not manually remove the first column but split all columns in single and multiple columns.

Comment: `could have groups of 5` - so when names have groups of X, will all names have X amount of columns? or would you have cases when it is just Bob has 5 columns, and Mary has only 2 columns?

Comment: But depending on the operation it could be possible or not.  For example you could calculate the mean of different-size groups, but some other operations could not be defined.

Comment: You can keep it simple if you want. Except for what I said:  "It could even happen that some columns don't have it's twin column".
If a column it's alone (group size =1) just leave it as is. Let's say the other all have the same size.   So, we have size = 1 or size = N, with N fixed.

Comment: OK, I've found another problem with most of your solutions, if the columname  contains a number in the middle it doesn't work, you need to add a $ at the end of the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using base R:

```
cn <- unique(gsub("\\d", "", colnames(mydata)))[-1]
sapply(cn, function(x) mydata[[paste0(x, 1)]] - mydata[[paste0(x, 2)]] )
```

You can use this approach for any arbitrary number of groups. For example this would return the row sums across the names with the suffix 1 or 2.:

```
sapply(cn, function(x) rowSums(mydata[, paste0(x, 1:2)]))
```

This paste approach could be replaced by regular expressions for more general applications.

Comment: Is there any advantage of gsub over sub in this problem?

Comment: In this case, I can't see why there would be a difference.

Comment: How would you modify your solution to add a "d" as a prefix of every new column, such as dMay, dBob, dDylan... ?
I've tried assigning paste0("d",cn)  to colnames()  but maybe there is a more direct way within your sapply.

Comment: `paste0("d", cn)` seems like a fine way to change the column names to me

Comment: For the addition to your question, one option would be to use table to group the columns by size of groups. For example, something like `cn <- table(gsub("\\d", "", colnames(mydata)[-1]));
cn <- names(cn[cn > 1])` would only take the names that occur more than once.

Comment: That is similar to my rle solution

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like,

```
sapply(unique(sub('\\d', '', names(mydata[,-1]))), 
       function(i) Reduce('-', mydata[,-1][,grepl(i, sub('\\d', '', names(mydata[,-1])))]))
#       Mary    Bob  Dylan    Tom  Jane    Sam  Tony   Luke   John    Pam
#[1,] -0.106 -0.335 -0.696  0.284 0.567  0.029 0.303  0.272 -0.274 -0.397
#[2,]  0.723  0.526 -0.119 -0.369 0.530 -0.118 0.308  0.159  0.686  0.313
#[3,]  0.174  0.230 -0.259 -0.454 0.039 -0.383 0.193 -0.028 -0.203  0.255
```

As per your comment, we can easily sort the columns and then apply the formula above,

```
sorted.names <- names(mydata)[order(nchar(names(mydata)), names(mydata))]
mydata <- mydata[,sorted.names]
```

Comment: It seems more compact than NBATrends solution but if some columns position are reversed it gives the negative of the expected result.
try with mydata <- cbind(mydata[-2],mydata[2])

Answer (score 1):

This solution handles an arbitrary number of twins.

```
## return data frame
twin.vars <- function(prefix, df) {
    df[grep(paste0(prefix, '[0-9]+$'), names(df))]
}

pfx <- unique(sub('[0-9]*$', '', names(mydata[-1])))

tmp <- lapply(pfx, function(x) Reduce(`-`, twin.vars(x, mydata)))
cbind(id=mydata$id, as.data.frame(setNames(tmp, pfx)))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the advantage of your solution against NBATrends' ?

Comment: The advantage is that my solution also works when you have unpaired columns or more than two columns with the same prefix.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've chosen @NBATrends solution because it works well almost always and he was the first.

Anyway, I add my little contribution, just in case anybody is interested:

```
runs <- rle(sort(sub('\\d$', '', names(mydata))))

sapply(runs[[2]][runs[[1]]>1], function(x) mydata[[paste0(x, 1)]] - mydata[[paste0(x, 2)]] )
```

The only "problem" is that it changes the final order, but you don't need to manually remove isolated columns, and works for disordered columns too.

I'm perplexed because nobody posted a solution with dplyr or data.table :)